# Automatically Create Chapters with Master Pages and XML

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, indesign-scripting, xml

I'm working on a catalog that contains several chapters and well over 100 pages. Luckily, I know that each chapter will be four pages long and use the same four Master Pages.

In a perfect world, I would have the client export their data as XML, with each chapter and all of its content being held by its child tags (number, title, description, etc.), and then just script the generation of the pages and let the XML fill it all out on import.

I was trying to do something like this

```
<catalog>
    <chapter>
        <number>
            01
        </number>
        <title>
            Super Awesome Title
        </title>
        <description>
            Here is the description for this chapter.
        </description>
    </chapter>
    <chapter>
        <number>
            02
        </number>
        <title>
            Another Title
        </title>
        <description>
            And another description.
        </description>
    </chapter>
</catalog>
```

but it's only importing the first set, and I kind of figured this attempt was a long shot anyways. I also tried using

```
<chapter1>
    <number>
        ...
<chapter2>
    <number>
        ...
<chapter3>
    <number>
        ...
```

though I couldn't see how to wrap individual pages with a tag and it's moving away from the automation I'm working towards.

So, does it make sense what I'm doing, and is my proposed process logical and (more importantly) doable?

Thanks much.

Comment: ".. it's only importing the first set" – the first `<chapter>`? That should not be happening. If I use Import XML.. > your test file, I get both chapters.

Comment: Apologies - it does import both chapters into the XML structure pane, but if I have, say, page 2 and page 4 both using the same master page for "Chapter Introduction", and I've tagged text frames in that master page, it's using the first chapter tag to populate content for both pages 2 and 4. I was wanting it to look at the project and say, "OK, first instance of this master page being used, so first instance of the chapter tag has its contents inserted. Onto the second instance of the chapter intro master page, let's use the second instance of the chapter tag and its data now."